# References dealing with $\nabla f(p)$?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

What is the best reference you know dealing with gradient properties (related to maxima and minima) of functions from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$?

Recall the gradient of a function $f:U\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ defined on an open set $U\subset \mathbb R^n$ is given by:

$$\nabla f(p)=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(p), \ldots, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(p)\right).$$

I have checked several books and I was not happy with their exposition.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you unhappy with?

Comment: It is more of a subjective matter, it is the style of writing that bothers me (or, more precisely, does not fit me).

Comment: Without knowing what bothers you it is difficult to give a 'best reference' (if such a thing exists).

Comment: But, I ask what it is the "best" for you, and not for me..

Comment: I don't know why the above definition does not work for you? Are you working in Hilbert spaces?

Comment: The definition is not the problem, it is the way it is approached. Different authors have different views, I'd like to check  different approaches =)

Comment: It is a plain matter, do you know any references you like? If you do and you would like to share I'll gladly check it, if you don't, that is ok.